# Android Navigation Component with Dynamic Bottom Tabs and Widget based UI

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

As per Navigation Component Library, we have to define a navigation graph with destinations and actions. It works fine for the use case where the flow of the app is well defined. In our use case, we have places where things are dynamic.

**1. Dynamic Bottom Tabs**
We have multiple modules in our app that can be shown in bottom tabs depending on the different properties like User is logged In or not, geography, etc. So, we have decided to get the config from the backend systems.

**2. Widget Base UI**
We are also working on our home page which can support multiple widgets from the backend where destinations are also dynamic.

Is there any efficient way to solve the same using the navigation component?

---

### Edit

*What do dynamic bottom tabs have to do with Navigation? What items appear in your bottom nav is not controlled by Navigation; those are just the Menu APIs on BottomNavigationView.*

Understood UI of BottomNavigationView is independent of Navigation. I want to solve the navigation from these tabs. For understanding the scenario take an example, I have 3 bottom tabs where the first one is home, the second is dynamic depends on the user state it could subscribe, favorites, recent depending on the backend configuration and third is profile.

- One way is to define every possible destination in the graph and then navigate using fragment id.
- Define global action for each possible combination then choose action as per the config.

*What do you mean by the 'destinations are also dynamic'? Do you mean that you dynamically change what screens you can navigate to from the home page?*

Yes. Widgets are dynamic on the home page and the same widget can also come on the favorites page which exists in a different tab. E.g. By one widget, I can go to profile in tab1.

Again the approach I can think of are following,

- Define a widget graph with all possible fragments as global action and then attach them with an individual page graph.

What is the better way to do so? Is there any other way to solve this problem in an efficient way? Can Kotlin DSL or creating graphs dynamically can help me solve these issues more efficiently?

Consider if there is a multiple back stack to manage how to do the same.

P.S.: App is multimodule. So, a destination could be a part of a different module.

Comment: What does dynamic bottom tabs have to do with Navigation? What items appear in your bottom nav is not controlled by Navigation; those are just the Menu APIs on `BottomNavigationView`. What do you mean by the 'destinations are also dynamic'? Do you mean that you dynamically change what screens you can navigate to from the home page?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am editing my question by addressing all these points.

Comment: @ianhanniballake https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1394737496357949443?s=09 This can help :)

Comment: Hello, have you implemented this? Which approach? Have you considered a case when some of the fragment tabs are actually the same fragment type with some initial param?